# Check what crashes my application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have an application written in C# / .NET 4 / VS C# Express. During debug session (it didn't happen with release build, but I can't say for sure, that it won't in future) my application exits, without any exception info. The only piece in my code, that closes main form, is accesible only with menu File/Exit and it's Clicked event handler. So it has to be some ... 'exceptional code'. How can I determine, which piece of code killed my app?

---

Solution if someone would like to use it:

```
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler( currentDomain_UnhandledException );
```

Event handler with file logging

```
void currentDomain_UnhandledException( object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e ) {
    using ( FileStream file = new FileStream( Application.StartupPath + "\\errorlog.txt",
        FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write ) ) {
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter( file );
        streamWriter.WriteLine( "-------------------------------------------------" );
        streamWriter.WriteLine( "---------- " + System.DateTime.Now + " ---------" );
        streamWriter.WriteLine( "-------------------------------------------------" );
        streamWriter.WriteLine( "Terminating: " + e.IsTerminating );
        Exception ex = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
        while ( ex != null ) {
            streamWriter.WriteLine( "--------- Exception: ---------- " );
            streamWriter.WriteLine( ex.GetType() );
            streamWriter.WriteLine( ex.Message );
            streamWriter.WriteLine( ex.HelpLink );
            streamWriter.WriteLine( ex.Source );
            streamWriter.WriteLine( ex.StackTrace );
            ex = ex.InnerException;
        }
        streamWriter.WriteLine();
        streamWriter.Close();
        MessageBox.Show( ( (Exception)e.ExceptionObject ).Message );
    }
}
```

Comment: have you checked the windows event logs? do you have any logs?

Comment: doesn't file->exit mean to exit your application?

Comment: Does the problem always happen in debug builds / is it reproducable?  Have you tried performing a clean build to see if the problem goes away?

Comment: @DanielA.White, part 1: yes, but found nothing, part 2: yes, but I've mean't that it is the only piece of code, which should exit, and which is not called with my "crash"

Comment: @forsvarir: this problem doesn't ALWAYS happen, that's why I can't really say what causes my problem, it requires a lot of comment-debug or debug-breakpoint-F10 work ... I'm looking for something faster, so I'll try the AppDomain.UnhandledException solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should have exception handling around all your code.

If it's still occurring you can attach an event handler to the [AppDomain.UnhandledException event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)

Note that your application is still going to crash, but this at least gives you the ability to log the exception.

Comment: Thanks, UnhandledException saved me ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would handle this event [App Domain Unhandled Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) and write the exception to some kind of file and see what the exception is.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting debug points on the main constructor and press F10/F11 etc until you know exactly where the application exists.

If this does not help, you might try F10 to start debugging your application from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure Thrown Exceptions as well as Unhandled Exceptions are checked in the Debug->Exceptions dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint at the beginning of your main() method, by either clicking in the margin or right-clicking in the code and selecting Insert Breakpoint.

Then start Debugging (F5). Then use Step Over (F10) and Step Into (F11) to step through/over your code line-by-line until you find the problematic code.

Answer (score 0):

All .net application crashes leave message in Windows Event log. Start your search from there. From what you have described it is either application  exit, or the crash.

There used to be debugging setting somewhere in Control Panel -> System -> Advanced, but I cannot find it on this machine. If enabled, each app crash would bring a popup if you want to debug the application or not. Could be a good start.